# How to append a row in a table widget PySide

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I have a PySide QTableWidget and i fill this table with items from QListWidget by running a function:

```
def fillTable(self):
    fruits = self.listWidget.selectedItems() # ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Coconut']
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(fruits))
    n = 0
    for i in fruits:
        item = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(n, 0, item) 
        item.setText(i)
        n = n + 1
```

Running this function again with another items in QListWidget replace items in a table. How to append a new items to existing items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add new elements you must increase the number of rows, and use the new positions. For this reason you must obtain the number of rows before the insertion to use the function `rowCount()` as shown below:

```
def fillTable(self):
    fruits = self.listWidget.selectedItems() # ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Coconut']
    n = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(n + len(fruits))
    for i in fruits:
        item = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(n, 0, item) 
        item.setText(i)
        n = n + 1
```

Comment: Thanks, man, that`s works!

Another question: i need a new function which will delete selected row from this table.

Comment: see [`removeRow()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#removeRow). ie `self.tableWidget.removeRow(row)`

Comment: And how to get selected row(rows)?

Comment: Use this: `rows = [self.listWidget.row(item) for item in self.listWidget.selectedItems()]

[self.tableWidget.removeRow(row) for row sorted(rows, reverse=True)]`

Comment: Thanks! Thats works:
`rows = [self.tableWidget.row(item) for item in self.tableWidget.selectedItems()] [self.tableWidget.removeRow(row) for row in sorted(rows, reverse=True)]`